# Parsing date with differents possible format

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java.time.instant

I have to parse a `String` to a timestamp in UTC. The `String` can have those format :

- `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ`
- `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss+/-hh:mm`
- `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss` (considered at UTC, so add a `Z` at the end)

What's the best way to do this and avoid :

```
    try {
        firstDateTimeFormatter.parse(string, Instant::from).toEpochMilli();
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        try {
            secondDateTimeFormatter.parse(string, Instant::from).toEpochMilli();
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e2) {
                thirdDateTimeFormatter.parse(string, Instant::from).toEpochMilli();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Test the length of the String?

Comment: Maybe use `regex` to determine the type first,and then parse it?

Comment: `Regex` would be a better option to test the format first and then parsing.

Comment: This question explicitly uses java.time, the modern Java date and time API, so cannot possibly be a duplicate of a question asking about the old and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options. Here’s a simple one:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[XXX]")
                .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

public static Instant parse(String offsetDateTimeString) {
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetDateTimeString, formatter).toInstant();
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(parse("2018-08-04T21:41:55.987Z"));
    System.out.println(parse("2018-08-04T19:41:55.987-02:00"));
    System.out.println(parse("2018-08-04T21:41:55.987"));
```

This prints:

```
2018-08-04T21:41:55.987Z
2018-08-04T21:41:55.987Z
2018-08-04T21:41:55.987Z
```

The square brackets in the format pattern string surround an optional part, so the offset may be present or not. Offset `X` uses `Z` for offset zero so matches the first two of your three formats. To specify the offset to use if there isn’t any in the string I have set a default time zone of UTC on the formatter.

Variations include:

- You may use predefined ISO formats rather than writing the entire format patterns string yourself.
- Since we are after an offset, not a time zone, it may be more correct to specify a default offset rather than a default time zone.

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` allows us to do both. So here’s a different formatter you may use in the above code instead:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendPattern("[XXX]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, ZoneOffset.UTC.getTotalSeconds())
        .toFormatter();
```

Results are identical.